# TypeScript equal value and equal type doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I just starting with TypeScript. I using TypeScript for my new AngularJS project. I run into the problem that id from type number is actually a type of string. Did I miss a case?

```
interface IRouteParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
    id: number;
}

class FooController {
    constructor(private $routerParams: IRouteParams, private fooService: IFooService) {
        fooService.getById($routerParams.id);
    }
}

export interface IFooService {  
    getById(id: number): ng.IPromise<number>;
}

class FooService implements IFooService {

    getById(id: number): angular.IPromise<number> {
        const defer = this.$q.defer<IRace>();

        if (id === -1) {
           // not working           
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then make it a string?

Comment: yes I could. I could also do `fooService.getById(Number($routerParams.id));` But what is then the whole purpose to use TypeScript? `getById(id: number)` just take a number. The `IRouteParams` inferface declare `id` as a type number as well..

Comment: TypeScript does not change the runtime behavior of external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route parameters are always strings (because they come from the URL). Writing `id: number` in TypeScript doesn't change that. You should write `id: string` when defining a route parameter.

Comment: [TypeScript cast of string to number](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/typescript-cast-of-string-to-number)